# How to ping docker container from VM on the same host?

Tags: docker, networking, virtual-machine, ping, opensuse

I have a docker container and a virtual machine(VM) on the same host(OpenSUSE). the docker has the IP like `172.18.0.2` and the host IP is something like `3.204.XX.XX` and VM IP is also something like `3.204.xx.xx`, I am able to ping the docker from the host and even the VM is pingable from the host and vice-versa but I am unable to ping the docker from the Virtual machine present on the same host. Is there a way to access the docker on the host from the VM present on the same host? please help.

Answer (score 3):

it is not possible directly because docker creates its bridge "bridge0" all the traffic is been routed using nat, where as virtualbox also creates its own bridge/interface , because of which its not able to access. But you can access by exposing port.
above mention requirement is possible with consul service discovery and host n/w config modification